# How to send keys from excel sheet to browser with new line

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to send keys to the browser using VBA. At the text box  I received the values in the same line. How can I get each value in the new line.

```
Sub testEdgeAuto()
    Dim obj As New WebDriver

    obj.Start "chrome", ""
    obj.Get " https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amazon-kw-index-and-rank/dehlblnjjkkbapjemjbeafjhjpjoifii?hl=en"
    obj.FindElementByClass("webstore-test-button-label").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

    obj.Get ("chrome-extension://dehlblnjjkkbapjemjbeafjhjpjoifii/index.html")

    obj.FindElementById("keywords").SendKeys (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value)

End Sub
```

For this I am getting output on browser as:
[image: output]

But I want to get output as:

[image: desired output]

Please help me in this regard.Thanks

Comment: What Object is `obj`?  That would make it a lot easier to look up the relevant documentation.  Please try to provide an [mcve], and *don't put code in images*.

Comment: I upload the complete code